# how to rename the Linux OS name installed in USB stick (LIVE USB)

Tags: linux, grub, live-usb

I am looking for the solution for modifying the query. The requirement is as follows

1. Installing the Any Linux OS in USB stick, here i have installed Fedora 21.
2. Now I need to rename Fedora OS to "Nik OS", Change the startup Icon too.
3. I need to remove the default popup "Try it or Install to Hard Drive".

Please guide me on this and how it is possible.

Thanks, Nikhil Joshi

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With lots of Research and googling I found that I need to follow the below steps:

1. Create your own linux Distribution. using http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/ . Make sure you set install on USB or LIVE USB capability
2. Install the new linux distribution on your usb drive.
3. Install your grub giving path of USB drive.
4. Change the default Program you want to start after the os loads

I will share more details once these starts in Live mode.

Thanks,

Nikhil